# Replace background in video by opencv

Tags: c++, opencv

I am looking for method and implementation to replace background in video. My goal looks like [Youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=G_AVZ8GZbTw). The author said that he used threshold value to extract background and replace them. However, I don't believed that threshold can acheived very nice result. Could you suggest to me any method that available in opencv for real time replacing background in opencv.

Answer (score 1):

Notice that "original camera" is not moving at all and the person appears after few seconds in the scene.

It is quite possible that first frame captured by the "original camera" is treated as "background". Simple thresholding based on comparition between RGB values form "background" and next frames when person appears in the scene can give such results.

If camera resolution of "originalvideo" and "reVideo" are the same this task becomes trivial.

Comment: Thanks. Do you have any example for that task

Comment: I found the idea of that method. Firstly, he captured the background (without person), And then he compare it when person is comming. It is quite simple but the performance is very good. Do you have any way to compare between background and the person+background

Answer (score 1):

Use the thresholded binary image as mask in cvCopy function.